# Playing an .m4a audio file in an HTML page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, audio, compression, html5-audio, lossless-compression

I'm trying to play an **m4a** file on a webpage and it doesn't work.
I'm using the **voice memo** app on an iPhone to generate these files.

#### I notice the following (Findings):

- When I switch my settings IOS > Settings > voice memo > Audio quality to **compressed** it works.
- When I switch my settings IOS > Settings > voice memo > Audio quality to **Lossless** it doesn't work.

#### The problem

The problem is that all the files that I need to use were generated using the **Lossless** setting.

Any ideas???

- why the browser is not playing these files?
- any suggestions to make it work?

#### Here is my snippet:

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="fileURL">
  <source src="fileURL">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: Btw, The player doesn't play and there are no errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: Have you tried going to the file's directory in your browser? Sometimes, when you place the directory in the URL bar, it goes to your audio file and plays it. Does that work?

Comment: possibly helped by adding the type tag in the source as in ...   `<source src="/media/foo.wav" type="audio/wav">`   ......  change value of type= based on corresponding file type

Comment: @KinoBacaltos, the file protocol won't work because I'm pulling these files from a remote server

Comment: @ScottStensland I just tried and it didn't work. I have try a lot of types and they didn't work neither

Comment: Can you re-encode the files to a supported format?

Answer (score 1):

The lossless files will most likely be encoded with [Apple Lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Lossless). As the name implies this is the format that Apple software uses to produce lossless files. To be sure you could open the files with Quicktime or iTunes to see what codec is used.

As far as I remember not even Safari for iOS does play Apple Lossless files natively. If you can't re-encode the files [alac.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/alac.js) could be an alternative. It's an Apple Lossless decoder written in JavaScript.